# Detection for spoofed useragents at client-side

Tags: javascript, user-agent

More and more users seem to seem to use spoofed useragents.

Of course, styles and designs should not be depending on useragent or unreliable details, but for analyzing this movement, I am trying to collect scripts and snippets for detecting false or spoofed useragents.

There are few differences, also depending on browser type, browser version and also OS.

Do You know a client-side javascript verficiation script that can add some more hints or ideas for how to "filter" them?

Comment: If a user decides to modify his useragent - why aren't you respect this?

Comment: How would you detect a spoofed useragent? Normally this is done with things like cURL where you can set whatever headers you want, and then you'd just copy the headers from the browser you want to mimmic, and there's no way to tell the difference. How would clientside checking avoid this, or have any relevance to spoofed headers at all ?